# Put files with certain name to a folder with its name

Tags: python

I have a couple of files inside  a folder called: `output`.

The files are `a.shp, a.dbf, a.shx, b.shp, b.dbf, b.shx`, etc .
How to make a folder 'exports' inside `output` and then inside 'exports', one called `a` and put automatically there `a.shp, etc` and so on for the other letter files?

Example:

```
from glob import glob
folder = C:/Users/user/Desktop/programs/merge/output
for i in glob(folder + '/*'):
    if ('a') in i:
         print(i)
```

gives

```
C:/Users/user/Desktop/programs/merge/output\a.dbf
C:/Users/user/Desktop/programs/merge/output\a.shp
C:/Users/user/Desktop/programs/merge/output\a.shx
```

What I tried:

```
from glob import glob
folder = C:/Users/user/Desktop/programs/merge/output
os.mkdir(folder +'/'+ 'exports' )
for i in glob(folder + '/*'):
    if ('a') in i:
        os.mkdir(folder +'/'+ 'exports' + '/' + i.split("\\")[-1]) 
# Creates a folder for each extension as well which is not needed. I want only by the name.
# and somehow all these files have to be moved to these folders
```

Answer (score 1):

Put some order or you'll end up MAD:

```
from shutil import copyfile


folder = C:/Users/user/Desktop/programs/merge/output
export_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'exports')
os.mkdir(export_folder)
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    file_without_extension = filename.split('.')[0] #ASSUMING THEY ONLY HAVE ONE DOT
    output_dir = os.path.join(export_folder, file_without_extension)
    os.mkdir(output_dir)
    copyfile(os.path.join(folder, filename), os.path.join(output_dir, filename))
```

Comment: Why i get this: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: Because you don't have permission either to create the directories or to copy the files in them, or to read the files, change the os.mkdir and shutil.copy for prints and check the directories that appear and their permissions

Answer (score 0):

From Rakesh's answer. With an edit that made it work. His answer, aside from permission errors also made an 'exports' folder inside the 'exports' folder too.

```
if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder, 'exports')):     #Check if 'exports' folder exists.
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(folder, 'exports'))              #Else create folder.

for file in os.listdir(folder): 
    if '.' in file:           #this addition made it work.
        filename = file.split(".")[0]         
        dest = os.path.join(folder, 'exports', filename)       
        if not os.path.isdir(dest):
            os.mkdir(dest)
        copyfile(os.path.join(folder, file), os.path.join(dest, file))
```

To the original poster: If you can explain why it made these folders 'exports' like that and edit your answer with this edit that fixed it I will accept yours and delete this.
Thanks for the idea.